# Returning projection with jsonb field

Tags: kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa, projection

I'm using JPA as persistence API for a project. It contains an entity which has a Postgres `jsonb` column, such as below:

```
@Entity
@TypeDefs(value = [TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType::class)])
data class Post(
    //... irrelevant columns
    @Type("jsonb") @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb") val postDefinitions: List<Map<String, Any>>
)
```

This works perfectly when fetching all data from this entity. But now I don't need to return all of it, but some fields, including the `jsonb`.
That's where things get ugly. I have this projection object and I'm using the following native query to retrieve the data, but somehow JPA can't map it.

```
interface PostProjection {
    val id: UUID
    val postDefinitions: List<Map<String, Any>>
}

@Query("SELECT CAST(id AS VARCHAR) AS id, jsonb_array_elements(post_definitions) AS postDefinitions " +
    "FROM post WHERE id = :postId", nativeQuery = true)
fun getPostDefinitionsById(val id: UUID): List<PostProjection>
```

It already has the `getters` and `setters`. I have tried annotating the interface with `@TypeDefs`, the column with `@Type` and changing it from `interface` to `data class`.

No success. Couldn't find anything about this. I wouldn't like to retrieve a `String` and then map it to the corresponding data type.

Has someone went through it?

Comment: I used a different implementation (not spring-data-jpa) but chaning type to Object helped me. `val postDefinitions: Any?` Moreover, posting the came with the error would help.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and found a solution: just create a constructor with an object instead of yours and cast it inside: here is my projection

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class MobileProductDetails extends MobileProduct {

    public MobileProductDetails(...
                                Object technoCodes,
                                String keywords,
                                Object documents,
                                Object children,
                                String url) {
        ...
        this.technoCodes = (List<String>) technoCodes;
        this.keywords = keywords;
        this.documents = (List<Integer>) documents;
        this.children = (List<Integer>) children;
        this.url = url;
    }

   //....

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    private List<String> technoCodes;

    private String keywords;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    private List<Integer> documents;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    private List<Integer> children;

    private String url;

}
```

And here is my query

```
"SELECT new ru.*.repository.projection.MobileProductDetails(" +
            "       P.id," +
            "       P.article," +
            "       PI.title," +
            "       P.shortName," +
            "       P.name, " +
            "       P.unitName," +
            "       P.type," +
            "       PI.group.id," +
            "       P.passportRequired," +
            "       PD.textDescription," +
            "       PD.textInterpretation," +
            "       PD.textStatement," +
            "       PD.textPreparation," +
            "       PI.material," +
            "       PI.technoCodes," +
            "       PI.keywords," +
            "       PI.documents, " +
            "       PI.children, " +
            "       PI.url" +
            ") " +
            "FROM Product P " +
            "INNER JOIN ProductInfo PI ON PI.article = P.article " +
            "INNER JOIN ProductDescription PD ON PD.article = P.article " +
            "WHERE P.deleted IS FALSE " +
            "       AND PI.deleted IS FALSE " +
            "       AND P.id = :productId " +
            "       AND PI.country = :country " +
            "ORDER BY PI.sort ASC "
```

Comment: Most of the time it is not a good idea to use Object as a parameter, as an object which does not contain the needed fields may be passed, resulting in an error